# Hide text in html which does not have any html tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML code here down below and there is text which does not have any HTML surrounding. Is there any method to hide the text "Enter" **which is after "p" tag**?

```
<div class="entry">
<p class="page-header" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Enter</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
Enter <-- i want to hide this text
<div class="subhead"></div>
</div>
```

It is not possible to wrap it with a div or any other tag, so I need some different decision like JavaScript or some CSS?

Comment: you can always use span to wrap it. No there is no other way if its not wrapped with tag.

Comment: In CSS is not possible, just do it with jQuery.

Comment: @LuísP.A. can you give me some hint how to do it with jQuery

Comment: this text can be anywhere on the page ? or just in this `p` tag ? @SergiKhizanishvili

Comment: where does the    div   end?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would consider a CSS hack with font-size:

```css
.entry {
  font-size:0;
}
.entry * {
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
<p class="page-header" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Enter</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp; somethin here</p>
Enter (this will be hidden !!)
<div class="subhead">another text here</div>
</div>
```

Another idea with `visibility`:

```css
.entry {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.entry * {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
<p class="page-header" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Enter</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp; somethin here</p>
Enter (this will be hidden !!)
<div class="subhead">another text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just note that screen readers will still read out both Enters

Answer (score -1):

Do you think it will works

```
var ele =document.getElementsByClassName('entry')[0]
ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild)
```

Comment: it will remove last element

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late response but this is how you can do it with `jquery`. Just get all the content of a div, filter the content with no tags around and wrap them inside `span` with style property as `display:none`. This will hide that text for you.

```js
$(".entry")
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() !== "";
}).wrap("<span style='display:none' ></span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry">
<p class="page-header" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Enter</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
Enter <!-- i want to hide this text-->
<div class="subhead"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks