# css select inner text not child

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sample HTML

```
 <li class="order-overview__total total">
    Total:                  
    <strong>
       <span class="price-amount amount">
         <span class="price-currencySymbol">$</span>**29.99**
       </span>
    </strong>
 </li>
```

how to select only the amount which is in this particular example is 29.99? I've tried `li.total span.amount`but I'm getting also the span. Also, `li.total span.amount:not(span)` is not working. I'm doing it in console `document.querySelectorAll("li.total span.amount:not(span)")`. What I want is get the actual value excluding the symbol.

Comment: for what purpose ? to only style it ? or to get the value ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609258/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one selector. I like @temani-afif 's answer because of its simplicity (and low complexity). But there might be reasons to extract DOM nodes instead of just the text value. You could do it with two loops:

```
// loop through all .amount spans
document.querySelectorAll("li.total span.amount").forEach(x => {
    // loop through all child nodes of .amount
    x.childNodes.forEach(y => {
        const nv = y.nodeValue;
        // ignore HTML nodes (nodeValue=null) and empty strings
        if (nv && nv.trim()) {
            console.log(nv);
        }
    })
})
```