# How can i select the parent element without child?

Tags: css

i don't know how to select only the h1 without the span in css
HTML:

```
  <h1>
    <span>hello from spam</span>
    <br> 
    heloo from h1 
  </h1>
```

Comment: you want to apply a style to only the text and not the span?

Comment: you would need to style the h1 and then re-style the span or do you mean you only want to style `h1`s if they don't contain a span?

Comment: what are the style that you want to apply ?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609258/8620333

Comment: yes @TemaniAfif

Comment: ... you did not clarify, maybe `:first-line` (css1) was plenty enough https://jsfiddle.net/at09msz1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no parent selectors in CSS. Check:

[Is there a CSS Parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

[Parent selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)

What you can do is styling both elements and then re-writing the style for the child. e.g.:

```
h1{
    color:blue;
}

h1 > span{
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <h1 id="h1">
        <span>hello from spam</span>
        Hello, world!
      </h1>
h1
{
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4b0000;
}
span
{
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #2f5000;
}
h1:has(span):hover
{
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can add style inside tag `<h1>` . For example:

```
<h1 style="color:red;">
```