# How to Change Content Button in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to change content "Turn On" into "Turn Off" button in HTML using CSS, but somehow it doesn't work don't know why, hier is the code...

```css
button{
 content: "Turn Off";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button>Turn On</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't delete *part* of text using CSS..and your HTML does not seem to match your CSS code. `content` is not inteded to be used for this purpose. `content` is for psuedo-elements and **styling**

Comment: what shoud I do? I want to change text in Button "Turn On" into "Turn Off" without changing HTML

Comment: you can use `::before` from button

Comment: if I use **::before** then it turns out **Turn OffTurn On**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried myself to do so, but it does not seem to work with only CSS.
JavaScript is a better solution.
To make it run, place the Javascript code in your HTML document between `<script></script>` tags, just before the `</body>`closing tag.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('input');

btn.addEventListener('click', updateBtn);

function updateBtn() {
  if (btn.value === 'Turn On') {
    btn.value = 'Turn Off';
  } else {
    btn.value = 'Turn On';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Turn On">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

try like below

```css
button:before {
  content: "Turn Off";
  font-size: initial;
}

button {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Turn On</button>
```

Related: [Hide text in html which does not have any html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609258/8620333)