# Css select span

Tags: css

How to select a span with value 34 but without 00?

```css
.simple-price span.price {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p class="simple-price">
  <span class="price">34<span>00</span></span>
  <span class="uah">грн/шт.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: you want to color only the span 34???

Comment: You can't do that with vanilla CSS!

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You _have_ selected only that span element. But `color` is one of the CSS properties that _inherits_ the value from the parent element, if not explicitly set.

Comment: yes, i  want to color only the span 34

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609258/8620333

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes it can. It's perfectly valid thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

```css
.simple-price span.price {
    color: red
}

.simple-price span.price > span{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<p class="simple-price">
    <span class="price">34</span>
        <span>00</span>
    <span class="uah">грн/шт.</span>
</p>
<p class="simple-price">
    <span class="price">34
        <span>00</span>
     </span>
    <span class="uah">грн/шт.</span>
</p>
```