# Remove text in HTML page not inside element tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is probably a very novice question but not sure how one could achieve this. There is an html page that shows as follows

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div><p>Hello!</p></div>
      <"
   </body>
</html>
```

My question is, is there a way to either remove or color the `<"` which is outside an html element via javascript or css?

Comment: what do you want? remove this `<"`? will this be the same for always ?

Comment: Hello @DupinderSingh yes this is correct

Comment: Is there some reason you can't access the source code and delete Phineas from the HTML directly?

Comment: Yeah one of those weird learning requirements, thank you so much!

Comment: Use NotePad++ and it will be black instead of blue...

Comment: if you want the CSS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49609442/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Jquery using this:

```js
$('body').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <div><p>Hello!</p></div>
 
 <"

</html>
```

Comment: to use this method you will download excess unnecessary 84kb downloading the jquery lib

Answer (score 4):

Converting Pablo Salazar's answer to use vanilla JavaScript, no need for a massive library. Also going with the "colour it" option.

```js
[...document.body.childNodes].filter(n=>n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    .forEach(n=>{
        const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
        wrapper.style.color = 'red';
        n.replaceWith(wrapper);
        wrapper.append(n);
    });
```

```html
 <div><p>Hello!</p></div>
<"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dangerous way

```js
var body_element = document.querySelector('body');
body_element.innerHTML = body_element.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;"|<")/, '');
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div><p>Hello!</p></div>
      <"
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you are right. But it solves the task :)

Comment: That's... not even remotely the point. It does the *very specific* thing, but in a way that causes *immeasurable* damage in side-effects. If this is how you code for real, I pray for anyone who has the misfortune of hiring you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nextSibling property and then .remove() mehtod

```js
document.querySelector('div').nextSibling.remove();
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
<"
```