# Remove dots that are not inside an HTML tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML structure like this: https://pastebin.com/jJLrAWcg

and I want to remove the dots that are not inside a tag example in line 42:

[image]

I've tried this code but it didn't work for me :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
for txt in soup.find_all(text=True, recursive=False):
    if not txt.strip():
        continue
    txt.extract()

print(soup)
```

Comment: The problem is that your dot IS inside a tag `<div class="recommandation"...>`; not sure what it's doing there (maybe simply a typo?) but it's there, so `soup.find_all(text=True)` will find it as well.

Comment: @JackFleeting well yeah the file contains some problems so am fixing it, when i do `soup.find_all(text=True)` i lose other tags

Comment: @user16085212 Just pass `True` instead of `text=True`. See my below answer

Comment: BTW, you don't need to pass `True` since the args is optimal here.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Correct, in the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#true) they _do_ pass `True` so I decided to include it.

Comment: @MendelG when i remove `recursive=False` it gets messy

Comment: I'm not sure how to further help. Maybe @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη  can provide an answer instead

Comment: @user16085212 `bs4` is a parser at 1st place. in case if you need to clear a messy `HTML` where you actually have a logic so you don't need to use a parser. read the `HTML` file as a text and regex `itemprop="reviewBody">.` where the dot occur and remove it!

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I thought about that. It's a much better approach. Either way I edited my answer which should work

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη i did find a working solution with jquery here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62808342/15336413, so i thought it must be a way to do it with bs4

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/RcFqCD/1

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη it's working thanks, if i didn't find a bs solution i'll use this regex thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("your_page.html", "r") as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "html.parser")

for txt in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if txt.strip() == ".":
        txt.extract()

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) property to search for all dots (`.`), and [`extract()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
    p class="overallRating"&gt;
<span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
 <meta content="10" itemprop="bestRating"/>
 <span itemprop="ratingValue">
  8
 </span>
 .
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for txt in soup.find_all(True):
    next_tag = txt.next_sibling
    if not next_tag:
        continue
        
    try:
        if next_tag.strip() == ".":
            next_tag.extract()
    except TypeError:
        continue


print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
p class="overallRating"&gt;
<span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
 <meta content="10" itemprop="bestRating"/>
 <span itemprop="ratingValue">
  8
 </span>
</span>
```

Comment: it does mess with other tags and remove some others

Comment: it did work for rating part, but not in recommandation

Comment: @user16085212 Can you explain a bit more? share an example, I didn't read the entire HTML

Comment: here is my whole html file: https://pastebin.com/jJLrAWcg, check line 42 that's where the recommandation part starts, and if u see in the picture i've shared you will see 2 additionnal dots , that's what i want to remove, the dots are always following this pattern : <tag>.<tag>, so i want to remove every dot that is not inside a tag

Comment: @user16085212 In total there's only two dots, correct?

Comment: no there is 3 first one in rating , two others in the first paragraph in recommandation

Comment: @user16085212 What are their line numbers?

Comment: line 42, 102 and 103