# How to delete a <div> element where only unique identifier is html text with no tags

Tags: html, css

My previous question was closed because it supposed that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609258/hide-text-in-html-which-does-not-have-any-html-tags) would answer my question. However, it does not, because it's not really what I'm asking. I'm not looking just to remove just the HTML text `Received`, but the whole row the `0 <3 Received`. Simply using `display: none;` would do. My issue though is that in CSS I can't figure out what selector to use, as it seems the only thing that differentiates between elements in that list is the HTML text in the center, like "Received," or "Given," and that HTML text can't be accessed with CSS since it's not a valid selector. So what do I do?

Note that I need a purely CSS solution, if possible. The html is at the mobile page of [mathbymiles.com/u](http://mathbymiles.com/u).

[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="ember69" class="user-stat ember-view"><span class="value">
    <span class="number">0</span>
</span>
<span class="label">
  <svg class="fa d-icon d-icon-heart svg-icon svg-string" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use xlink:href="#heart"></use></svg>
  Received
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.number, .label{ display: none; } `
why would not that work?

Comment: you have an ID and a 2 classes. What you want more?

Comment: The `div` has an ID called 'ember69', then if you want to delete or hide it, then use  `#ember69 { display: none }`. # selects HTML elements with ID  . (dot) selects HTML elements with classes

Comment: None of these work either because 1) I can't use ember selectors because they are dynamically generated, or 2) the solution deletes the information from ALL rows, instead of only the "0 <3 Received" row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not use any identifiers like classes or ids, you can rely on DOM structure pattern. Just try this:

```css
.user-info + .user-stat {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work because it removes the information from ALL of the other rows too. I just want the row "0 <3 Received" removed. That's really the essence of my problem here...

Comment: @Wesley Please check the screenshot from my answer.

Comment: Oh, nice, it worked for me. But how can I similarly get rid of "0 Given"? If you can tell me that then I think you've solved my problem.

Comment: `.user > .user-stat:nth-child(3) { display: none }`

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need to read more up on the "+" and ">" ways of getting the correct selectors. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I can recommend you to try css-diner: https://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229272/discussion-between-wesley-and-ortophius).

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
.number, .label{ 
      display: none; 
}
```

To remove the content of the row, or try

```
#ember69{ 
   display: none 
}
```

To remove the whole row.

Comment: No. This doesn't work because .label {display: none;} removes all of the labels, not just "received." Also, I think the ember names are dynamically generated, so this is not a solution either (not to mention that in the end I want to remove 0 <3 Received for every user.)

Comment: Then what exactly do you want? Do you have acces only to the css?

Comment: Correct. I am using Discourse forum software, and they use Ember.JS. I can only change things with CSS, which is usually fine since there are a lot of selectors; it's just this one case where it seems very difficult to "select" this particular element. I would ask on the Discourse forum, but they don't like me asking purely CSS questions over there.

Comment: Well I'm sorry to tell you, but I think in this case it's quite impossible to do so... I have tough one more idea.

Comment: How many  instances  of the `user-state` are there before the one you want to delete?